# how to use snakemake parameters in a chain?

Tags: python, workflow, snakemake

I'm creating a snakemake rule, and I want to use one parameter as the input for another snakemake parameter. I want to know how you refer to other parameters in the same params chunk of a snakemake rule

`

```
#create a map of the bid and the vcf
bid_to_vcf={}
for vcf in config['vcf_samples']:
    bid = vcf[0:5]
    if bid not in bid_to_vcf:
        bid_to_vcf[bid]=vcf
        

# Define a rule template
rule all:
    input:
        expand("output/{sample}.txt", sample=config['samples'])


rule phaser_step1:
    input:
        # get the path to the bam file
        input_file = "{sample}.txt"
        
    params:
        #get the BID from the sample
        bid=lambda wildcards: wildcards.sample[:5],
        
        #get the vcf vial number from the bid
        vcf_vial=bid_to_vcf[bid], ################## this is not working
        
        #get the actual vcf path
        vcf_path=vcf_dir + vcf_vial + ".vcf.gz" ############# this line says 'vcf_vial is not defined'
    
    output:
        join('output', "{sample}.txt")
        
    shell:
        """
        echo {input.input_file}
        echo {params.bid}
        echo {params.vcf_vial}
        echo {params.vcf}
        cp {input.input_file} > {output}
        """
```

`as the comments show, I can set the bid variable just fine, but then when I try to use bid to create the vcf*vial variable, nothing happens. this has a chain reaction, because then when I try to create vcf*_path, I get a not defined error.

Would appreciate any tips, super new to snakemake! Thanks in advance

Edit: The error message is this:

```
NameError in file /phaser/Snakefile, line 53:
name 'vcf_vial' is not defined
  File "phaser/Snakefile", line 53, in <module>
```

Comment: need more information on wildcards according to your code bid seems to be defined as a lambda function instead of a variable also paste the error you are getting if possible

Comment: added the error message to the post, can you clarify what you mean about bid being defined as a function instead of a variable? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure whats going on with `bid` and `vcf_vial`, but I was able to make this work:

```
from pathlib import Path
# fake data
vcfs = ["bid_1.vcf", "bid_2.vcf"]
samples = ["bid_1_sample1", "bid_2_sample2"]
vcf_dir = "vcfs"

#create a map of the bid and the vcf
bid_to_vcf={}
for vcf in vcfs:
    bid = vcf[0:5]
    if bid not in bid_to_vcf:
        bid_to_vcf[bid]=vcf
        
def get_vcf(wildcards):
    bid = wildcards.sample[:5]
    vcf_vial = bid_to_vcf[bid]
    vcf_path = Path(vcf_dir, f"{vcf_vial}+.gz")
    return vcf_path
# Define a rule template
rule all:
    input:
        expand("output/{sample}.txt", sample=samples)


rule phaser_step1:
    input:
        # get the path to the bam file
        input_file = "{sample}.txt"
        
    params:
        vcf = get_vcf
    
    output:
        "output/{sample}.txt"
        
    shell:
        """
        echo {input.input_file}
        echo {params.vcf}
        cp {input.input_file} {output}
        """
```

Run with `snakemake -n`:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Job stats:
job             count
------------  -------
all                 1
phaser_step1        2
total               3


[Tue Nov 28 10:21:15 2023]
rule phaser_step1:
    input: bid_2_sample2.txt
    output: output/bid_2_sample2.txt
    jobid: 2
    reason: Missing output files: output/bid_2_sample2.txt
    wildcards: sample=bid_2_sample2
    resources: tmpdir=/var/folders/3k/ffyrjn4x7px101x_wvrk5q9h0000gn/T


[Tue Nov 28 10:21:15 2023]
rule phaser_step1:
    input: bid_1_sample1.txt
    output: output/bid_1_sample1.txt
    jobid: 1
    reason: Missing output files: output/bid_1_sample1.txt
    wildcards: sample=bid_1_sample1
    resources: tmpdir=/var/folders/3k/ffyrjn4x7px101x_wvrk5q9h0000gn/T


[Tue Nov 28 10:21:15 2023]
localrule all:
    input: output/bid_1_sample1.txt, output/bid_2_sample2.txt
    jobid: 0
    reason: Input files updated by another job: output/bid_1_sample1.txt, output/bid_2_sample2.txt
    resources: tmpdir=/var/folders/3k/ffyrjn4x7px101x_wvrk5q9h0000gn/T

Job stats:
job             count
------------  -------
all                 1
phaser_step1        2
total               3

Reasons:
    (check individual jobs above for details)
    input files updated by another job:
        all
    missing output files:
        phaser_step1

This was a dry-run (flag -n). The order of jobs does not reflect the order of execution.
```